# How can I create login and sign up using phone number with firebase android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml

Is it possible to make Android app login with a phone number and password (not email and password) using Firebase Realtime Database?

Answer (score 0):

There is a phone number sign-in method in firebase authentication where users can login with phone number and otp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

First add your project to Firebase. [Follow this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)
You need to integrate firebase sdk for your app.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
```

Enable phone number authentication in Firebase console.

Use this code to send a sms for authentication.

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
    60,                 // Timeout duration
    TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
    this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
    mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
```

For callback and more info, [Read the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)